# Pass v4sf by value or reference

Tags: gcc, optimization, sse

Which is more efficient of passing a SSE vector by value or reference?

```
typedef float v4sf __attribute__ ((vector_size(16)));

//Pass by reference
void doStuff(v4sf& foo);

//Pass by value
v4sf doStuff(v4sf foo);
```

On one hand, v4sf is large 16 byte.
But, we can deal with these things as if they were single element data, and the reference may introduce one level of indirection

Comment: I would use `static inline v4sf doStuff(v4sf const & foo)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically SIMD functions which take vector parameters are relatively small and performance-critical, which usually means they should be inlined. Once inlined it doesn't really matter whether you pass by value, pointer or reference, as the compiler will optimise away unnecessary copies or dereferences.

One further point: if you think you might ever need to port your code to Windows then you will almost certainly want to use references, as there are some inane ABI restrictions which limit how many vector parameters you can pass (by value), even when the function is inlined.

Comment: I would suggest with MSVC to use const references (e.g. `v4sf doStuff(v4sf const & foo)`) otherwise you get an error like "error C2719: formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned".

Comment: I've found that MSVC fails to inline even trivial functions when they are called hundreds of times. `__forceinline` is the only to make it behave.

Comment: Indeed - it's a good idea to use a macro, e.g. `FORCE_INLINE` which expands to `__forceinline` for MSVC and `__attribute__ ((always_inline))` on gcc *et al*.